# Struggling to prove (or disprove) that, given four positive integer numbers a,b,c,d, $a^2-b^2$ = $c^2-d^2$ only if a=b and c=d

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the intuition that given four positive integer numbers a,b,c,d, $a^2-b^2$ = $c^2-d^2$ only if a=b and c=d, but cannot seem to be able to prove it.

Any help with this?

Many thanks,
AdV

Comment: I have the opposite intuition.

Comment: $7^2-1^2 = 8^2 - 4^2$, $7^2 - 2^2 = 9^2 - 6^2$

Comment: $15^2+20^2=25^2=7^2+24^2$ so $24^2-20^2=15^2-7^2$

Comment: The opposite direction is trivial... $a^2-a^2=c^2-c^2$ is obviously true.

Comment: As a general note:  If we can factor a number $n$ as $m\times k$ where $m>k$ are either both odd or both even, then we can solve $a+b=m,a-b=k$ in integers.  If we can get several such factorings for a single $n$ we get many representations of $n$ as a difference of two squares.

Comment: Only if $a=b$ and $c=d$. That means $0 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is false, consider the number 32.  $$32 = (8)(4) = (6+2)(6-2) = 6^2 - 2^2$$
$$and$$
$$32 = (16)(2) = (9+7)(9-7) = 9^2 - 7^2$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)
$$
That means that for each way to write a natural number into the difference of two squares, there is a corresponding way to factor that number into the product of two factors. The difference between these factors is $2b$, which means that the two factors are either both even or both odd.

Conversely, for each way there is to factor a number into the product of two factors of the same parity, there is a corresponding way to write that number as the difference between two squares. Indeed, if $n=pq$ is such a factorisation, then
$$
n=\left(\frac{p+q}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{p-q}2\right)^2
$$
So, if there are two ways to factor $n$ into two factors of the same parity, then there are two ways to write it as the difference between two squares.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexamples are easy to come by. For instance,

$4^2 - 1^2 = 15 = 8^2 - 7^2$.

In general,

$(n+3)^2 - n^2 = 6n + 9$
$= (3n+5)^2 - (3n+4)^2$.

Comment: Many thanks to all. Overwhelmed by my stupid question :-) I was only looking for a way to prove it and obviously failed. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have the $37^2-35^2=13^2-5^2=12^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a^2-b^2=c^2-d^2$ implies $(a+b)(a-b)=(c+d)(c-d)$

Now assume that all the numbers involved are positive integers and that $a\gt b$ (you can solve the general problem from knowing the answers with these restrictions).

Now note also that $(a+b)=(a-b)+2b$. It follows that the factors have the same parity, so all are odd, or all are even. If the factors are the same on either side, you have $a=c, b=d$

Take the odd case with both sides equal to $pqrs$ where $p,q,r,s$ are all odd.

Suppose $a+b=pq, a-b=rs, c+d=pr, c-d=qs$ then

$$a=\frac {pq+rs}2, b=\frac {pq-rs}2, c=\frac {pr+qs}2, d=\frac {pr-qs}2$$

In the even case both sides are equal to $4pqrs$ where $p, q,r,s$ are integers.

We can write $a+b=pq, a-b=rs, c+d=pr, c-d=qs$ when

$$a=pq+rs, b=pq-rs, c=pr+qs, d=pr-qs$$

So choosing appropriate values for $p,q,r,s$ gives many solutions (note that factors can be $1$, which is an odd positive integer).